# How do I block hackers or bots from accessing newsletter signup

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I am receiving large amounts of newsletter subscription signups which are coming in at a rate that is too fast to be real. When I looked up the ips from my online customers, some of the ips are proxy ips and other ips from Russia, Ukraine and France. I disabled newsletter signup and blocked a whole lot of ips, and when I enable it again, I was fine for a day or two and it started up again. Are these hackers or bots? Does anyone know how I could stop this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of techniques you can use to protect your forms from bot spam. E.g you could add a CAPTCHA question, or add a hidden 'honeypot' field and only accept the submission if the field is ommited. These approaches might not be be 100% affective but should help reduce spam.

Answer (score 1):

For a 1.9 install, i think this is the best solution i have found so far.

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam

It will set a new system to check if there is a bot trying to submit the form and if the bot is filling out the for too fast for a human user.